# create custom attribute for class property

Tags: c#, attributes

I am working on console application. I want to make sure that when values assigned to my class properties it should do basic validation. I read about "creating custom attribute" but not able to understand how to implement in my case. for e.g.

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Required]
    public string id;

    [ContainsNumeric]
    public int cost;

    [ContainsChar]
     ...

    [ContainsDate]
    ....
}
```

I created Required attribute and ContainsNumeric only class but don't know how to access actual class properties within those classes.

```
class ContainsNumericAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public ContainsNumericAttribute() : base()
        {
                   ?????
        }
    }
class RequiredAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public RequiredAttribute() : base()
        {
                ???
        }
    }
```

Please help me with example.

Comment: Why don't you just do validations in the setters and provide a mandatory constructor ? Using attribute, you'll need to do run-time check by using reflection on each property to make sure it matches the attribute.

Comment: I have many classes that requires same kind of validation....So I want create separate class for validation...

Comment: Check the usage of attributes in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how to access the attributes using `Reflection`:

(Sure you need to move that to some helper class or something).

```
static bool Validate<T>(T obj)
{
    var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();

    foreach(var prop in properties)
    {
        if(prop.IsDefined(typeof(RequiredAttribute)))
        {
            object value = prop.GetValue(obj);

            if(value == null)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }

        if(prop.IsDefined(typeof(ContainsNumericAttribute)))
        {

        }
    }

    return false; // dummy value now
}
```

Usage:

```
MyClass cc = new MyClass()
{
    cost = 5
};

Validate(cc); // false, id required
```

If you want , you can create a validation results object and return it from `Validate` method add all validations that fails to that object.

Comment: Thanks....so are you saying that my ContainsNumericAttribute and RequiredAttribute  class will have no code!!??....and I have create something like "MyValidation" class with method static bool Validate<T>(T obj) and all validation logic will be in that Validate method?

Comment: @bansi Exactly. The Attributes themselves most probably don't have code. Unless you want to say `MaxLengthAttribute(5)`, then you need to have a constructor and store that 5 inside the attribute. But otherwise, No. Most of the cases, attributes are just flags or tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong idea of what attributes are and how they work. They will not add any validation here, unless your own code checks for their existence, and invokes code to *do that* (or unless you're using an IL-rewriter that does the same, such as post-sharp).

Basically: this isn't going to do what you want.

Comment: ya i agree, I am trying to understand how to implement custom attribute class. can you please tell me with example what to write in these attribute classes. I may have to create many more custom attribute class for e.g. class that check for so and so condition and if that satiated than make particular property of class as required property.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are not supposed to be used like that. If you really want to, you have to do some really complicated reflection, get those properties at runtime, and check their values... It's a mess!

I would suggest you to create a `PropertyValidatorClass`:

```
public static class PropertyValidator {
    public static bool Required<T>(T property) where T: class {
        // I think you want to check this?
        return property != nil;
    }

    public static bool ContainsNumeric(string property) {
        return ...
    }

    public static bool ContainsDate(string property) {
        return ...
    }

    public static bool ContainsChar(string property) {
        return ...
    }

    ...
}
```

And in each property's setter,

```
set {
    if (PropertyValidator.Required(value)) {
        Id = value;
    } else {
        // I dunno, throw an exception or something
    }
}
```

You can also modify the class so that you kind of have a fluent interface:

```
using static SomeNamespace.PropertyValidator;
...
if (Check(value, withRule: Rules.Required))
```

`Rules` is obviously an enum and `Check` is a method from `PropertyValidator`.

That's just some of my ideas.

Comment: If you think my Answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark! @bansi